# Regex Match any string powershell

Tags: regex, parsing, powershell, match

No matter how well I feel like I know regular expressions, they always seem to beat me.

I am looking for a universal pattern that will match any string. The only way I could figure out how to handle all these different naming conventions, was make a bunch of different regex patterns, and now I'm not even sure if all the data is getting picked up so I would have to manually cross-check it.

I am just trying to pick up anything that could possibly be within two brackets [ ] :

```
elseif($line -match "\[\w*\d*\]") {         
    $pars = $matches[0]
}
elseif($line -match "\[\d*\w*\]") {
    $pars = $matches[0]
}
elseif($line -match "\[\w*\d*_\w*\]") {
    $pars = $matches[0]
}
elseif($line -match "\[\w*\d*_*\w*-*\w*:*\w*\]") {
    $pars = $matches[0]
}            
elseif($line -match "\[\w*_*\w*_*\w*_*\w*_*\w*_*\w*-*\w*\]") {
    $pars = $matches[0]
}
```

The way I am doing it does not generate errors, but I am not sure it handles all the situations I could potentially come across. Checking manually is almost impossible with this much data.

Also, if anyone knows of a great utility for generating regex patterns it would be much appreciated.  I have only been able to find regex testers which isn't very useful to me, and there is little help online for regular expressions with powershell.

Comment: what did you mean by any string? does that means regex `.+` will do? and btw, `\d` and `_` is already included inside `\w`

Comment: You don't really describe very well what *exactly* you're trying to match inside the brackets.  From what I can infer from you're code, you're looking for any string that just has alphanumeric characters and the underscore.  If that's the case, you could just use `\[[\d\w]*\]` or `\[[a-zA-Z_0-9]*\]`....  Oh, I see a colon and dash in there too.  Well, in that case you can do `\[[\w\d:-]*\]`.

Comment: Angga got it on point. By any string I meant "Any Possible characters you can place in between 2 brackets". The `.+` handles that exactly. Thank you, post your solution so I can accept it as an answer

Comment: @Cole9350 It would be better to update the question with this information.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Please do not use your automated software to edit my questions / answers. The edits are not useful and do not make sense. Wikipedia is not a valid source to site for the change you suggested.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$a = [regex]"\[(.*)\]"
$b = $a.Match("sdfqsfsf[fghfdghdfhg]dgsdfg") 
$b.Captures[0].value
```

Comment: Perfect, This works just as well as `.+` , which leaves me to figure out the difference between greedy and ungreedy. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question ?

Comment: what happens if a string contains more than one ], ex "asdfasfd[asdf]sfafe]asdfs"? How to get "asdf" within [..]?

Comment: Use `$a.Matches()` instead of `Match()` to return multiple results - Match() seems to find one and then stop

Comment: @David.Chu.ca, `$a = [regex]"\[([^\[\]]*)\]"` will stop it from matching against the 2nd `]`

Answer (score 7):

Match everything that *isn't* a bracket.  Create a character class that contains anything but the bracket characters:

```
$line -match "\[[^\[\]]+\]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Focusing to

> "I am just trying to pick up anything that could possibly be within two brackets [ ]"

I think **`\[.*\]`** is what you are looking for.

**Explanation**
Sice **`[`** and **`]`** have special purposes, so you need to use `\` before those characters.
**`.`**(dot) stands for any character and
**`*`** stands for any number of repetition of the previous charector.
Here, the previous character is **`.`**, so **`.*`** stands for any general string.

Answer (score 0):

Matching anything between two brackets:

```
$text='[a[b]c] and [d text]'
$p = [regex]'\[[^][]*]'
$p.Matches($text) | % {Write-Host $_.value}
```

See [regex proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%5D&i=%5Ba%5Bb%5Dc%5D%20and%20%5Bd%20text%5D). **Results**:

```
[b]
[d text]
```

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^][]*                   any character except: ']', '[' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ]                        ']'
```

If the brackets need to be paired and can be nested:

```cs
\[(?>[^][]+|(?<g>)\[|(?<-g>)])*]
```

See [regex proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Cg%3E%29%5C%5B%7C%28%3F%3C-g%3E%29%5D%29*%5D&i=%5Ba%5Bb%5Dc%5D%20and%20%5Bd%20text%5D). **EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?>                      match (and do not backtrack afterwards) (0
                           or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^][]+                   any character except: ']', '[' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<g>)\[                '[' (empty match added to "g" group stack)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<-g>)]                ']' (empty match removed from "g" group stack)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ]                        ']'
```