# Bash: replace substring between quotes that contains any character type

Tags: regex, string, bash, replace

I am trying to edit part of a string using a Bash (version 3.2) script.

For example, in $line

```
line='<Coordinate text1="0" coordinateIndex="78?907??" anotherID="9098" yetanoherID="1.2.3" xyz:text="abc"/>'
```

I need to edit the contents of coordinateIndex (which can have any character/any length). My last attempt (below) doesn't give an error but doesn't solve the problem either:

```
echo "${line/coordinateIndex=\"\[(.*)\]\"/coordinateIndex="124"/line}"
```

I also tried using ")" instead of "]"; also .+, among many others.

The output I am looking for is:

```
line='<Coordinate text1="0" coordinateIndex="124" anotherID="9098" yetanoherID="1.2.3" xyz:text="abc"/>'
```

I tried solutions based on

[Regex Match any string powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000757/regex-match-any-string-powershell)

http://unix.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/shellscript-l/shell-script-to-replace-string-within-double-quotes-4107915

https://superuser.com/questions/515421/using-sed-get-substring-between-two-double-quotes

but I am still unable to solve this.

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is the character negation class, `[^"]`, which will capture anything that is not a `"`.  Example usage: `echo "${line/coordinateIndex=\"\[^\"\]*\"/coordinateIndex="124"/line}"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer; it doesn't work for me unfortunately...

Comment: Is there any reason why the square brackets are escaped?  Should it not read echo "${line/coordinateIndex=\"[^\"]*\"/coordinateIndex=\"124\"/line}"? note the addition of escapes on the quotations around the 124 in the replace.

Comment: That actually changes the coordinate index to 124! But doesn't copy the rest of the line. I get the output: <Coordinate text1="0" coordinateIndex="124"/line/>

Comment: you can not use '*' which matches any characters. you need extglob, something like the following:  shopt -s extglob; echo "${line//coordinateIndex=\"*([^\"])\"/coordinateIndex=\"124\"}";

Comment: The pattern in the shell search-and-replace syntax is a glob, not a regular expression. In a glob, * means any number of characters and ? means any single character. Bash globs also allow character classes and an extended syntax if shopt extglob is set. But random regular expressions culled from the internet won't work.

Comment: @rici I see. I will read more on globs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily with `perl`:

```
#!/bin/bash

str=$(cat << EOF
line='<Coordinate text1="0" coordinateIndex="78?907??" anotherID="9098" yetanoherID="1.2.3" xyz:text="abc"/>'
EOF
)

echo "$str" |perl -pe 's|(coordinateIndex=)".*?"|$1"abc"|g'
```

Output:

```
bash test.sh 
line='<Coordinate text1="0" coordinateIndex="abc" anotherID="9098" yetanoherID="1.2.3" xyz:text="abc"/>
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! But how can I replace "abc" with a variable $i? I tried $i, ${i}, $(i), but they produce the empty string or a wrong output. (Completely new to perl) - Thank you.

Comment: Do this: `perl -pe 's|(coordinateIndex=)".*?"|$1"'$var'"|g'` where `$var` can be any variable you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Bash regex matching.

```
var=coordinateIndex
value=124
if [[ $line =~ $var=\"([0-9|\?]+)\" ]]; then
    echo ${line/$var=\"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\"/$var=\"$value\"}
fi
```

They key here is to know which type of characters can be found in between the quotes after `coordinateIndex=`.  If you just use `*`, which matches any character, you'll end up matching and replacing everything up to the final `"` in the variable `line`.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your suggestion, which worked perfectly as well!